# Android Facebook SDK: does not send access token?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I'm using the following snippet to request the friendslist of the authorized user:

```
System.out.println("AT: " + facebook.getAccessToken());
String response = facebook.request("me/friends?fields=first_name,last_name,id,gender");
```

The response I get:

```
{"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}
```

I'm printing the accesstoken, this gives me a valid token. Also, `getAccessExpires()` returns a time in the future. When I request the url `"me/friends"` without any params, I get the expected (but with less data) friends list without errors.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> String response = facebook.request("me/friends?fields=first_name,last_name,id,gender");

That is the incorrect way to use `facebook.request`.  I'm assuming you're not using the beta Android SDK so the correct way to do this is to do the following:

```
Facebook facebook = new Facebook(YOUR_APP_ID);
AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.put("fields", "first_name, last_name, id, gender");
mAsyncRunner.request("me/friends", params, new RequestListener() {
    // get response here
    ....
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I actually chose not to use the `AsyncFacebookRunner`, using my own `AsyncTask` implementation. However, using the params `Bundle` instead of the plain stringurl solved the problem. Thanks for the hint in the right direction!